# Привязать домен пользователя к своему сервису

Tags: php, хостинг, домен, appdomain

Есть сервис (ака генератор лендингов для примера).
Живёт на домене mydomain.com
Задача: дать пользователю сервиса возможность привязать свой домен (userdomain.com) в админке, чтобы страницы моего сервиса были доступны по адресу его домена.

Куда копать? Может кто-то натыкался на соответствующие мануалы или реализовывал такую задачу?

Буду премного благодарен за любую информацию:)

Answer (score 0):

Это делается через конфиги веб сервера. Вам нужно изучить, как в http сервере, который Вы используете, реализуется подключение нескольких доменов и затем автоматизировать данный процесс и дать пользователю GUI в котором он будет указывать свой домен, что бы Ваше ПО могло сгенерировать конифг и отдать команду серверу его подхватить.

Разумеется, что у регистратора домена, который использует уже пользователь, А-запись должна смотреть на Ваш IP.

Это самая общая схема.

Comment: Благодарю. А подскажите как правильно сформулировать запрос для поиска примеров реализации?

Comment: Я в своё время искал: "Несколько доменов на web сервере [название_используемого_сервера]". Примерно, как-то так...